# Using MQMoveMessage

Tags: msmq, message-queue

I'm trying to add poison message handling in my message queuing implementation. I'm receiving a batch of messages from a transactional queue, lets say 100, and if any are deemed 'poisonness', I want to move them to a subqueue where they can be handled separately.

The problem I'm having is knowing how to use MQMoveMessage. If I use it using the same transaction as the receive, I get an MQ_ERROR_MESSAGE_LOCKED_UNDER_TRANSACTION result code. If I use it after the receive transaction, I [of course] get a MQ_ERROR_MESSAGE_NOT_FOUND result code.

I imagine this works if I peek the message, since that doesn't lock the message, or remove it from the queue. However, that doesn't help since I'm receiving, and using a transactional queue.

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Comment: The only pattern that seems to be working for me is...

Receive a batch of messages within a transaction. If a 'poison' message is not found, commit the transaction. Otherwise, abort the transaction, start a new transaction, moving the offending message to the subqueue, and commit that. Then try reading the batch again.
Seems to work fairly well, but it's a shame that I can't move the message during the receive transaction - after all, it is sort-of still in the queue up until the transaction is committed, so you'd think you'd have the option of moving it at this point..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone has the same issue, it appears the pattern is as above. That is, a transaction should be aborted, the message moves performed, and the transaction re-read.